# Vertices not being updated after changing position Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I merged multiple cubes together using `THREE.GeometryUtils.merge`, and I'm moving this merged object (a `THREE.Mesh` object) around by changing `object.position`.

The object is being moved fine, but when I'm accessing its vertices later for collision detection purposes, I realized that the vertices aren't getting affected by my changes to `position`. I've tried setting `verticesNeedUpdate` to true but that doesn't seem to help.

Does anyone know what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I just had to do `object.localToWorld(vertex)` to go from local vertex to global vertex. I wasn't aware of the local/global coordinates difference in Three.js so I was confused.

Hope this will help some other confused person!